# Create a dataset with dynamic number of rows based on shiny input

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app up with the data included. I want to create a line chart which will have in the x-axis the `Date` selected and in the y-axis the number of cases as they are computed by    `bupaR::n_cases(mydata2())`. So basically I need the initial dataset to be reformated in a way that it will have 2 columns `Month` and `Cases` and I will be able to include them on the chart but with the correct chronological order. For example `December 20` must be always be displayed before `January 21` even if `January 21` is selected first. I do not have problem if the Date columns must be reformated as well in order to achive this (for example it may be `2020-12` and `2021-01`

```
library(shiny)
library(bupaR)
mydata<-structure(list(case_id = c("WC4120721", "WC4120667", "WC4120689", 
                                   "WC4121068", "WC4120667", "WC4121937", "WC4121767", "WC4121952", 
                                   "WC4121889", "WC4121921", "WC4121870"), lifecycle = c(110, 110, 
                                                                                         110, 110, 120, 110, 110, 110, 110, 10, 110), action = c("WC4120721-CN354877", 
                                                                                                                                                 "WC4120667-CN354878", "WC4120689-CN356752", "WC4121068-CN301950", 
                                                                                                                                                 "WC4120667-CSW310", "WC4121937-CN301302", "WC4121767-CN354089", 
                                                                                                                                                 "WC4121952-CN355950", "WC4121889-CN301291", "WC4121921-CSW304", 
                                                                                                                                                 "WC4121870-CN301116"), activity = c("Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
                                                                                                                                                                                     "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
                                                                                                                                                                                     "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "BBH-1&2", "Needle Point", "Brazing Machines", 
                                                                                                                                                                                     "Needle Point", "Needle Point", "SOLO Salt", "Needle Point"), 
                       resource = c("3419", "3216", "3409", "3201", "C3-100", "6206", 
                                    "7709", "6201", "5202", "C3-040", "5503"), timestamp = structure(c(1606975200, 
                                                                                                       1607126280, 1607446560, 1607578920, 1607641020, 1609695420, 
                                                                                                       1609696800, 1609697040, 1609697460, 1609697460, 1609700340
                                    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Date = c("December-20", 
                                                                                                "December-20", "December-20", "December-20", "December-20", 
                                                                                                "January-21", "January-21", "January-21", "January-21", "January-21", 
                                                                                                "January-21"), .order = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
                                                                                                                          89L, 90L, 91L)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("eventlog", 
                                                                                                                                                                              "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "action", lifecycle_id = "lifecycle", resource_id = "resource", timestamp = "timestamp")
ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput("mon","month",choices = unique(mydata$Date),selected  = unique(mydata$Date),multiple = T),  
verbatimTextOutput("cases"),
plotOutput("linechart")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 mydata2<-reactive({
   my<-subset(mydata,Date%in%input$mon)
 }) 
 output$cases<-renderPrint({
   bupaR::n_cases(mydata2())
 })
# output$linechart<-renderPlot({
#   ggplot(data=mydata2(), aes(x=Date, y=#cases
#                               )) +
#     geom_line()+
#     geom_point()
# })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question the goal is to show the cases per date. To this end you could transform your data using:

```
dat <- mydata2() |> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
```

And full reproducible app code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(bupaR)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("mon", "month", choices = unique(mydata$Date), selected = unique(mydata$Date), multiple = T),
  verbatimTextOutput("cases"),
  plotOutput("linechart")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydata2 <- reactive({
    my <- subset(mydata, Date %in% input$mon)
  })
  output$cases <- renderPrint({
    bupaR::n_cases(mydata2())
  })
  output$linechart<-renderPlot({
    dat <- mydata2() |> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
    ggplot(data = dat, aes(x=date, y = n_cases)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6871
```

[image]

Comment: could u check this shiny issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744699/use-the-edges-dataframe-which-is-included-inside-a-process-map-object-to-subse